# using an update query inside a select SQL injection (oracle)

Tags: oracle, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I got an SQL injection point which allows me to insert anything after a Select keyword , such as :

```
Select ID FROM %INJECTION POINT%
```

is there anyway to complete this query to make an update for a table ? without using a ";" ?

Comment: Yes, there is but why do you need that?

Comment: why do I need that ? I'm working on a project which I'm stuck in this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in oracle , unless you use an existing user function to do so